# Skip after the label of inline description environment

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

I'd like to turn a paragraph containing several “subparagraps” into an equivalent inline list. See the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% \usepackage{tikz}

\newlist{description_inline}{description*}{1}
\setlist[description_inline]{format=\myformat}
\newcommand \myformat [1] {\normalfont\emph{#1}}

\newlist{description_inline_fixed}{description*}{1}
\setlist[description_inline_fixed]{format=\myformatfixed, afterlabel=\unskip}
\newcommand \myformatfixed [1] {\normalfont\emph{#1} }

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \emph{Case A.} We do something to show Case A. \emph{Case B.} Now we proooooooooove Case B.
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{description_inline}
            \item[Case A.] We do something to show Case A.
            \item[Case B.] Now we proooooooooove Case B.
        \end{description_inline}
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{description_inline_fixed}
            \item[Case A.] We do something to show Case A.
            \item[Case B.] Now we proooooooooove Case B.
        \end{description_inline_fixed}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The following proofs are produced:
[image: The proofs produced]

It seems that there is a stretchable skip after every label, which may cause ugly spaces depending on line break. That's why I put `\unskip` after every label. But is it the right solution?

And why this problem occurs in the first place? I don't see any benefit of having there the stretchable skip. It feels wrong when I learn about inline lists, try them, and the first thing I get looks like a bug.

Also feel free to suggest any other changes in the code.

**Updated:** When I tried to use my solution in my thesis, it just didn't work. The ugly spaces appeared no matter of `\unskip` being used. After some time I found out, that it doesn't work when TikZ is used. What the heck?!

Comment: Where are those ugly spaces? If I compile you MWE the problem is not obvious to me

Comment: BTW: from a reading standpoint, having all cases be inline like this might not be the best solution, a reader might loose track of that we are currently dealing with.

Comment: @campa: I'm putting there a space in `\myformat` because I want there a normal space, `\unskip` should destroy the stretching one.

Comment: @daleif: In the presented MWE, the problem shoud be fixed by the `\unskip`, but it is reintroduced if TikZ is used.

Comment: @daleif: I agree that having the cases inline might not be the best –  it really depends how the cases are long or complicated. But that is the point of the `description_inline` environment – I may easily switch to ordinary `descripion` if necessary without needing to edit the contents.

Comment: Please post an image of what you see

Comment: @daleif: I've change the code a bit to better expose the problem and also added an image.

Comment: not a good solution: the whitespace comes from an `\hfil` in the definition of `\enit@align@left` in _enumitem.sty_. You could re-define that command or get rid of it by something crazy like `\newcommand*\ignorenext[1]{}` and `\newcommand\myformat[1]{\normalfont\emph{#1.} \ignorenext}`.

Comment: @wrtlprnft: But `\unskip` should swallow that `\hfill` right? But why doesn't it work with TikZ. And why are thy putting there `\hfil` when we are in inline list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, there's an `\hfil` that gets inserted after the item label to get it to align left.  Fortunately, we can change the alignment with the `align` option and define new alignment types with `\SetLabelAlign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlist{description_inline}{description*}{1}
\setlist[description_inline]{format=\myformat}
\newcommand \myformat [1] {\normalfont\emph{#1} }

\SetLabelAlign{don't}{#1}
\newlist{description_inline_fixed}{description*}{1}
\setlist[description_inline_fixed]{format=\myformatfixed,align=don't}
\newcommand \myformatfixed [1] {\normalfont\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \emph{Case A.} We do something to show Case A. \emph{Case B.} Now we proooooooooove Case B.
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{description_inline}
            \item[Case A.] We do something to show Case A.
            \item[Case B.] Now we proooooooooove Case B.
        \end{description_inline}
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{description_inline_fixed}
            \item[Case A.] We do something to show Case A.
            \item[Case B.] Now we proooooooooove Case B.
        \end{description_inline_fixed}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

While I have no idea why enumitem tries to align inline list items in the first place, this option seems safer to me than any method for deleting the `\hfil` after or before it has been inserted. If the package is ever changed to skip the alignment step, the `align` option will hopefully safely become a no-op.

Comment: That's an elegant solution. Thank you very much for your insight.